# Thevenin's Equivalent using KCL - Circuit Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I've been struggling for so long on this practice question for circuit analysis. Am new to this topic so would really appreciate some guidance! :)

The question is as follows: With the load Rl removed, find Vthv (using KCL) and Rthv across terminals A and B.

[image]

I ended up finding the potential difference across the 10k ohm resistor, which I'm sure is incorrect. I'm used to seeing single-port outputs and this circuit doesn't resemble any of the examples in my lecture notes. D:

edit: here is my most recent working, i removed the 10k ohm resistor and found Va and Vb.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. We don't just hand out solutions to homework or exam questions here, so show us the steps you took to calculate the voltage across the 10k resistor and we can see if you're going about this the right way.

Comment: @Finbarr done! sorry about not posting it earlier, i knew my answer was wrong and was a little embarrassed about how shaky my foundational knowledge is

Comment: So far so good, now transform both voltage dividers into voltage sources with impedance.

Comment: hm, the problem statement asked to remove R_L, not the 10 kΩ in parallel to it.

Comment: You can replace the left side by a 12 V source with a series resistance of 4 kohm.

Comment: ...so do the same to the right hand side, then replace the 10k resistor and you have two voltage sources with three resistors in series between them. The last line of your solution is wrong because you haven't worked out the Thevenin resistance for the two sides.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to address the title of your question and, as you say, assume that this is a *practice question for circuit analysis*.

> Thevenin's Equivalent using KCL - Circuit Analysis

I gather that \$R_{_\text{L}}\$ is not to be included in the analysis except that what is desired is what \$R_{_\text{L}}\$ ***sees*** looking into the two terminals to which it connects.

To find the Thevenin all you need to do is to remove \$R_{_\text{L}}\$ and replace it with a current source that is set to \$0\:\text{A}\$ and to \$1\:\text{A}\$. The change in voltage across the current source divided by the difference (which is **1**) gives the Thevenin impedance and the voltage across the current source when set to \$0\:\text{A}\$ is the Thevenin voltage. It's really just no more complex than that.

Let's consider the current source, \$I_x\$, is pointing such that the positive value of the current is removed from **B** and injected into **A**. (Arrow points from **b** and into **A**.)

The KCL is:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{5\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{20\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{10\:\text{k}\Omega}&=I_x+\frac{15\:\text{V}}{5\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{20\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{10\:\text{k}\Omega}
\\\\
\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{5\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{30\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{10\:\text{k}\Omega}+I_x&=\frac{10\:\text{V}}{5\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{30\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{10\:\text{k}\Omega}
\end{align*}$$

Using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) (Python):

```
va,vb,ix = symbols( 'va,vb,ix', real=True )
e1 = Eq( va/5e3 + va/20e3 + va/10e3, ix + 15/5e3 + 0/20e3 + vb/10e3 )
e2 = Eq( vb/5e3 + vb/30e3 + vb/10e3 + ix, 10/5e3 + 0/30e3 + va/10e3 )
ans = solve( [ e1, e2 ], [ va, vb ] )

(ans[va]-ans[vb]).subs(ix,0)                              # Thevenin voltage
1.87500000000000

(ans[va]-ans[vb]).subs(ix,1)-(ans[va]-ans[vb]).subs(ix,0) # Thevenin resistance
4531.25000000000
```

The Thevenin voltage is then \$1.875\:\text{V}\$ and the Thevenin resistance is \$4.53125\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

*(Now, I focused on using KCL. But there are other methods that only require techniques usually taught **before** reaching chapters discussing mesh and nodal analysis (and various modified versions of same.) I can't tell if you really would have preferred using those prosaic methods. So I just focused on the title of your question.)*

Answer (score 3):

I will show how I would find the impedance between A and B, 1) if I have a simulator handy, and 2) by hand.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2HYOM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**If I have a simulator handy**, I would simply measure the voltage across A and B, and get 1.875 V. Then I short A and B, by changing R3 to \$0\Omega\$ and measure the current through R3 and get 0.4138 mA. Since this is a linear circuit, the impedance between A and B is then just the "open" voltage, divided by the "shorted" current or

$$Z = \frac{V_{open}}{I_{short}} = \frac{1.875}{0.4138} = 4.531k\Omega$$

This is how I would **solve the problem by hand** if I did not have a simulator handy.

First I would eliminate R2 and R4 by using the Thevenin equivalents of voltage dividers.

$$5||20 = \frac{100}{25} = 4 k\Omega$$
$$15 \cdot \frac{20}{25} = 12 V$$
$$5||30 = \frac{150}{35} = \frac{30}{7} k\Omega$$
$$10 \cdot \frac{30}{35} = \frac{60}{7} V$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgn37m.png)</sup>

With A and B open, (R3 is still in the circuit!!!), the current through R3 will be

$$\frac{12-60/7}{4 + 10 + 30/7} = \frac{84-60}{98+30} = \frac{3}{16} mA $$

The voltage across R3 would then just be

$$10\cdot\frac{3}{16} = 1\frac{7}{8}V$$

(exactly the same as given by simulation)

With A and B shorted, the current through the circuit would be

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUR6Yw.png)</sup>

$$\frac{12-60/7}{4 + 30/7} =  \frac{24}{58} = \frac{12}{29}mA $$

The impedance is then just

$$\frac{\frac{30}{16}}{\frac{12}{29}} = 4.53125 k\Omega $$

Comment: Your resistance units are off, you forgot to add k's

Answer (score 2):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. I know that this approach is not 'smart' but this method will work all the time, even when the circuit is (way) more complicated than this one. Also, this method will check your work.

Well, we are trying the analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faH9Nn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_2
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_6}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

We can now substitute \$(1)\$ into \$(2)\$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can set up a Mathematica code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3 + I6, I4 == I3 + I5 + I6, I4 == I0 + I5, 
   I1 == I0 + I2, I1 == (Va - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1 - 0)/R2, 
   I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, I4 == (V2 - 0)/R4, I5 == (Vb - V2)/R5, 
   I6 == (V1 - V2)/R6}, {I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> ((R3 + R6) (R2 (R4 + R5) Va - (R1 + R2) R4 Vb))/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5) + (R2 R3 R4 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6), 
  I1 -> ((R3 R4 R5 + R4 R5 R6 + R3 (R4 + R5) R6) Va + 
    R2 (R3 + R6) ((R4 + R5) Va - R4 Vb))/(
   R2 (R3 R4 R5 + R4 R5 R6 + R3 (R4 + R5) R6) + 
    R1 (R3 R4 R5 + R4 R5 R6 + R3 (R4 + R5) R6 + 
       R2 (R4 + R5) (R3 + R6))), 
  I2 -> ((R3 R4 R5 + R4 R5 R6 + R3 (R4 + R5) R6) Va + 
    R1 R4 (R3 + R6) Vb)/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5) + (R2 R3 R4 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6), 
  I3 -> (R2 (R4 + R5) R6 Va - (R1 + R2) R4 R6 Vb)/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5) + (R2 R3 R4 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6), 
  I4 -> (R2 R5 (R3 + R6) Va + R1 R3 R6 Vb + 
    R2 (R3 R6 + R1 (R3 + R6)) Vb)/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5) + (R2 R3 R4 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6), 
  I5 -> (-R2 R4 (R3 + R6) Va + (R2 R3 R4 + R1 R3 (R2 + R4) + 
       R2 (R3 + R4) R6 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R6) Vb)/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5) + (R2 R3 R4 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6), 
  I6 -> (R2 R3 (R4 + R5) Va - (R1 + R2) R3 R4 Vb)/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5) + (R2 R3 R4 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6), 
  V1 -> (R2 (R3 R4 R5 + R4 R5 R6 + R3 (R4 + R5) R6) Va + 
    R1 R2 R4 (R3 + R6) Vb)/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5) + (R2 R3 R4 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6), 
  V2 -> (R1 R3 R4 R6 Vb + 
    R2 R4 (R5 (R3 + R6) Va + R3 R6 Vb + R1 (R3 + R6) Vb))/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5) + (R2 R3 R4 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6)}}
```

Now, we can find:

- \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2\$ and letting \$\text{R}_6\to\infty\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{15}{8}=1.875\space\text{V}\tag4$$
- \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_6\$ and letting \$\text{R}_6\to0\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{3}{7250}\approx0.000413793\space\text{A}\tag5$$
- \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{th}}{\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{th}}=\frac{18125}{4}=4531.25\space\Omega\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica codes:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[((R2 (R3 R4 R5 + R4 R5 R6 + R3 (R4 + R5) R6) Va + 
     R1 R2 R4 (R3 + R6) Vb)/(
    R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5) + (R2 R3 R4 + 
        R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
        R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6)) - ((
    R1 R3 R4 R6 Vb + 
     R2 R4 (R5 (R3 + R6) Va + R3 R6 Vb + R1 (R3 + R6) Vb))/(
    R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5) + (R2 R3 R4 + 
        R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
        R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6)), R6 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=(R2 R3 (R4 + R5) Va - (R1 + R2) R3 R4 Vb)/(
R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5)

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R2 R3 (R4 + R5) Va - (R1 + R2) R3 R4 Vb)/(
  R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5) + (R2 R3 R4 + 
      R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6), 
  R6 -> 0]]

Out[3]=(R2 (R4 + R5) Va - (R1 + R2) R4 Vb)/(
R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5)

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=(R3 (R1 R2 R4 + R2 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R4) R5))/(
R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5)
```

Comment: I've uploaded a slightly cleaned up version of your approach here: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/kuba0/Published/ee-678774.nb

Answer (score 1):

I went a bit of a long way to find the required Thevenin voltage and resistance. Unfortunately I used the A3 format for the pages, perhaps they are not readable, so I add the photos one page at a time.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]